# add a CSV dataframe to a dictionary separating by name

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, keras

So I am doing a Time series/LSTM assignment and I have a stock dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/sandp500

There are like 500 companies with a set of rows for each company, in the dataset, and what I want is to add the companies to a dictionary and set the key as the name of each company.

This is what I have for the moment:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('all_stocks_5yr.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
dataframe['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['date'])

grouped_df = dataframe.groupby('Name')

for i in grouped_df:
    df_dict = grouped_df[i].to_dict
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: When I ran the cell I get: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: to visualize the dictionary the dictionary I should create a variable and put dataframe.set_index('Name').T.to_dict('dict') inside? Do you know how can I print an expecific company with its columns from the dictionary? @A.Najafi

Comment: after looking at the dataset I find out we have multiple records for each company.
So, how do you want to handle them ?

Comment: I want to enter each company with all the records in the dictionary, set the name as the key. Then I want to select just the closing column and set a rolling window, to perfom a Kmeans method and create time series with that column for each company, I hope I explained myself clear, thank you @A.Najafi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would solve your problem:

```
gp = dataframe.groupby("Name")
my_dict = {} # This is the output you want
for record in gp: # record is a tuple containing the elements of a row
    if record[0] in my_dict: # record[0] will give the name of the company
        my_dict[record[0]].append(record)
    else:
        my_dict[record[0]] = [record]

print(my_dict)
```

Another way to handle this problem is iterating over the dataframe:

```
my_dict = {}
for index, record in dataframe.iterrows():
    if record['Name'] in my_dict:
        my_dict[record['Name']].append(record)
    else:
        my_dict[record['Name']] = [record]

print(my_dict)
```

Comment: Is there the key set as the name? I assume that as the dataframe is grouped by Name, that is also the key, isn't it?

Comment: when you groupby the dataframe based on `Name` , you can then apply a function over it using `apply` method. TBH, there is no need to do groupby,but whatever it works :)

Comment: YES!, i see now that the key of each batch is the name of each company. One last thing (I'm new to this, I'm sorry XD). Do you know how can I select one column (the closing column) from each company batch to later perform the time series exercise?

Comment: you can iterate over the ```my_dict``` and for each company, you can find it based on whatever you want. if my answer solved your problem, please accept it as the answer. GL